# What are the voltages noted next to the C-rates?

Tags: batteries

I am looking at a brochure/datasheet for some lead acid batteries, Hoppecke deep cycle gel, OPzV ([link to brochure](http://www.hoppecke.com/content/download/brochures/rp/OPzV_en.pdf)).

Below you see two snippets from it:

[image]

[image]

I have some problems understanding the C-rate concept in general, and I think the answer might lie in the noted voltages. So, what are the voltages noted next to each C-rate in the top of the columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Battery capacity is commonly specified as a current times a time, often using units of Amp-hours.  For example, 10 Ah means that *in theory* the battery can deliver 1 A for 10 h.

There will be some current range where you can trade off time and current linearly, but that relationship will fall apart at both low and high currents.  Using the above example, you could calculate that the battery should be able to deliver 10 A for 1 h.  The math is correct, but you have to look at the battery datasheet carefully to see whether 10 A is a valid discharge current, and if so, whether that is high enough to degrade capacity significantly.

In battery specs, "C" is understood to be the theoretical one hour discharge current, whether the battery is actually capable of that current or not.  When the capacity is specified in Ah, then C is the same number although it has units of amps instead of amp-hours.

Now look at your chart and take the top line, representing a single battery, as example.  C<sub>nom</sub> is the nominal single-spec capacity, which is 200 Ah.  This is further defined to be the 10 hour discharge rate, and measured according to a particular DIN standard.  The other C<sub>hours</sub> values are specified over different discharge times.

Although the snippet of the datasheet you show doesn't explicitly say so, the voltages in the column headings are almost certainly the terminating voltages for the discharge test.  Note that for higher discharge rates, like C<sub>1</sub> (200 A), the ending voltage is lower.  This is because at this higher current, there is some drop due to internal resistance, and there is still meaningful charge left in the battery until its external voltage goes down to that level.  Basically, these are the voltages at which you should consider the battery discharged for the indicated current.

Answer (score 3):

Those would be the voltage **per cell** at the end of the discharge curve.

For example, a 12V battery has 6 cells so the C3 discharge termination voltage would be 1.75V x 6 = 10.5V.

The Ah capacity numbers tell you the number of Ah the battery can supply if you discharge it from fully charged to the specified voltage per cell (in the specified number if hours). Discharging the battery below the specified voltage per cell generally doesn't give you much more energy, and it can damage the battery.

Comment: Fine, but where does the number 1.75V come from? Could they have chosen another smaller value, and then written a greater capacity at eg C3?

Comment: They have chosen a value that gives a reasonable balance between battery service life (number of cycles) and available energy. You can use a higher voltage (effectively derating the battery capacity) but you should not discharge the battery to a lower voltage per cell, or you're at risk of truncating the life of said battery.

Comment: But the whole idea of C-rates, is that it is a way of comparing battery technologies, eg one company vs another, normalized to the capacity. If two companies have totally identical technology, then one can choose 1.75V and another 1.70V, and the latter will come to higher capacity. On the other hand, a standard organization like DIN can not dictate a voltage of eg 1.75V (at C3), since company A might have good service life at 1.75V and company B at 1.70V

Comment: @MadsSkjern I don't think the idea is to make it possible for non technical people to compare. We always have to read and understand the "fine print".

Comment: Ok. But... :) Why do they even tell the reader (whether expert or not) this voltage in the brochure, he has no way of telling if it is a sensible value. They could write: "We stopped the discharge at a voltage that will not reduce the service life (unreasonably)" :)

Comment: Because the designer of the load should protect the battery and ensure that the load still operates so the need that information (really, the curve, and temperature and life effects) you can't have too much information.